# Extract information from Log file using Logstash

Tags: apache, logstash, logstash-grok

I had an unstructured logfile which through some modifications in unix i made structured. The log file looks as below:

```
Module: KFK_PIG_ETL_JOBVW_7DAYS: 2015-06-03 15 28 27,976 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2017  Internal error creating job configuration.
Module: KFK_SONORA_RM_LRF: >>> [ERROR] Wed Jun  3 08 25 07 PDT 2015   Executing command  ssh -K data_svc@lva1-tarockgw01.grid.linkedin.com "export KRB5CCNAME=/export/home/data_svc/krb5cc_data_svc ; hadoop  fs -D appworx.chain.id=2905148 -D appworx.agent=LVA1-ETL04 -D appworx.job.id=2905178.00 -rm -r -skipTrash /jobs/data_svc/etl/tracking/lrf/STG_DAILY_JOB_VIEW/20150602-20150602.gz       "
```

I am trying to use Logstash to extract the below required information from above log.

- Module
- Timestamp
- Error

Basically after extracting all the above 3 fields from log , I want to show in Kibana dashboard that for a period of time and for a particular module what type of errors came.

Can someone suggest the logstash conf file patterns for the same.

Comment: Since it doesn't "answer" your question, I'll leave this as a comment: go to the grok debugger, enter one of your lines, and start building the pattern - one piece at a time from left to right.  Then test it in logstash.

Comment: I totally agree with Alain. That's also why I didn't answer. Your given log lines are very different and have varying timestamps and so on. The grok debugger is a good start. Here is the link: http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/